# Demoting to float2 when using seq with double2 arrays in ArrayFire

Tags: parallel-processing, arrayfire

I'm using the following test code exploiting the ArrayFire library.

```
void test_seq(const array& input, array& output, const int N)
{
    array test      = seq(0,N-1);                                         
    output          = input;
}

(for the moment `array test` has no role)

double2* test_CPU; test_CPU=(double2*)malloc(10*sizeof(double2));       
for (int k=0; k<10; k++) { test_CPU[k].x=2.; test_CPU[k].y=1.; }
array test_GPU(10, test_CPU);
array test_GPU_output = constant(0.,10, c64);
test_seq(test_GPU,test_GPU_output,10);
print(test_GPU_output);
try {
    double2 *CPU_test = test_GPU_output.host<double2>();
    printf("%f %f\n",CPU_test[0].x,CPU_test[0].y);
} catch (af::exception& e) {
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", e.what()); 
}
```

and everything compiles and runs correctly.

However, then I change the above function to

```
void test_seq(const array& input, array& output, const int N)
{
    array test      = seq(0,N-1);                                         
    output          = input * test;
}
```

I receive the following runtime error message

**src/gena/gtypes.cpp:112: error: requested cuDoubleComplex from array of type cuComplex**

If, on the other side, I change the line

```
double2 *CPU_test = test_GPU_output.host<double2>();
```

to

```
float2 *CPU_test = test_GPU_output.host<float2>();
```

everything runs fine again. It seems there is a demotion to float2 connected with the use of `seq`. The above problem does not disappear if I use something like `seq(0,N-1,f64)` (I even do not know if it is allowed by ArrayFire).

How can I keep `double2` processing and avoid demoting to `float2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When converting seq to array, it is stored as single precision (float).

Currently in arrayfire, the rule for an operation involving two arrays from different precision is to choose the lower precision. This is the reason `input * test` is getting converted from double precision to single precision (and hence `float2`).

The solution for now is to add the line below the generation of test.

```
test = test.as(f64);
```

It will add very little overhead, because the array is not generated until necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. I will try your solution. Unfortunately, right now neither my code nor the ArrayFire examples are working. I think I have temporarily a licence issue (although my internet connection works fine). I will let you know. Again, thanks.

Comment: @JackOLantern email me (email available on my profile) if you are having continued trouble.

Comment: I solved the license problem. It was a failure in my internet connection. Also, your solution worked correctly. Thank you. I have accepted your answer.